# How to extract a substring from a field in logstash?

Tags: logstash

I'm trying to extract a substring ("groceryGateway") from a field. I'm using grok and logstash but I am having trouble.

I've tried using the patterns provided in grok, but I cannot extract the substring I would like.

```
{
    "@timestamp" => 2019-07-29T16:35:54.256Z,
          "host" => "MacBook-Pro-51.local",
      "@version" => "1",
       "message" => "Iogo 0% Multi Pack With Stevia Strawberry/Blueberry/Vanilla/Mango,5.99, 16x100g,https://www.grocerygateway.com/store/groceryGateway/en/Yogurt-and-Cottage-Cheese/Multi-Pack/Iogo-0%25-Multi-Pack-With-Stevia-Strawberry-Blueberry-Vanilla-Mango/p/00629025420053\r",
          "name" => "Iogo 0% Multi Pack With Stevia Strawberry/Blueberry/Vanilla/Mango",
          "path" => "/Users/kevinliu/Desktop/Wanda/thanos/output_data/grocery_gateway-2019-07-25_16:17.csv",
          "type" => "grocery_item",
          "unit" => " 16x100g",
           "url" => "https://www.grocerygateway.com/store/groceryGateway/en/Yogurt-and-Cottage-Cheese/Multi-Pack/Iogo-0%25-Multi-Pack-With-Stevia-Strawberry-Blueberry-Vanilla-Mango/p/00629025420053",
          "test" => "0",
         "price" => "5.99"
}
```

Comment: Care to share what you've tried so far? and what you're getting as the output?

Comment: Something with `%{URIPROTO}://%{URIHOST:domain}` should be a good start.